# Adding Entries to HKCU for all users

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a registry file for each users when they first log in. I was looking at different options to add `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` but couldn't get a definitive answer. Need someone to direct me to the right direction.

So I have the following commands

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\foo.reg" /v "Version" /d "1" /t REG_SZ /f 

add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\C:\mykit\foo.reg /v "EnableRPCEncryption" /d "1" /t REG_DWORD /f" /f
```

Ican execute them and but the reg_key doesn't run when I first login as a new user.

I am running windows 2012 server

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Even if you find a way to enumerate all users that ever logged in to this computer, that won't help future users or users that haven't logged in to the computer yet. If you want to share a registry key with all users, put it in HKLM. Alternatively you can add a login script to write this key.

Comment: There is no `reg` command on the second line.

Comment: @Mofi You can import files created with the REG command or which are properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the appropriate registry settings within HKU.Default using the same relative paths. Log in with a new user and check to see that the settings are present.

You can also create a Group Policy Object (GPO) that runs for all users and checks to see if the HKCU registry key is present and adds if necesary.

If you are not keen on GPO, you can write a batch file and place it in within the startup folder of the All Users Start Menu.